# How can i set color to input box

Tags: html, css

How can I set a color for the input boxes? a link would be helpful too, thank you!

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Last Name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" required>   
</div>
```

Comment: By color do you mean the background-color?

Comment: Yes, background color for the input box :last name and first name

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp87knxe/

Check this.

Comment: You wanted some links, so here you go! https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```css
#Last {
background-color: red
/* Set to any color you want :) */
}
#First {
background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Last Name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" id = "Last" required>   
</div>
<br>
<!-- Added a <br> to make it look better, but it is not necessary -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="First Name"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" name = "box2" size = 15 maxlength = 30 required id="First">
  
</div>
```